# Magento 2 - redirect from old store view code to a new one with routes.yaml?

Tags: magento, magento2

I changed store view code and now I am thinking can I use file routes.yaml in magento 2 to redirect from old store view code to a new one?

Because for example if someone bookmarked store url with old store view code, I want to be sure that this url will lead to a new one.

So, can I use routes.yaml file to redirect from store view code /1 to store view code /2?